# select varias colunas group by 1 coluna

Tags: sql-server, select

Tenho uma tabela com 300mil registros e dentro dela existem varios campos diferentes, eu gostaria de pegar a linha que contem a maior DATAEMISSAOAPURADA      para cada CPF_1

o que eu tenho:

```
ID          NUMERO                    DATAEMISSAOAPURADA      COD                     NOMEMUNICIPIORESIDENCIA                            UFRESIDENCIA CPF_1         CPF_2         FONTE               NOME                                                                         DATA                        DATA         
----------- ------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
12345       0000000000000009116092003 2007-11-19 00:00:00     4200051                 Abdon Batista                                      SC           123           321           TB1                 To***********                                                                2012-10-28 00:00:00         NULL
78999       0000000000080697220782003 2007-11-09 00:00:00     4200051                 Abdon Batista                                      SC           123           321           TB1                 To***********                                                                2012-10-28 00:00:00         NULL
12347       C000000000000000000821022 2006-04-12 00:00:00     2302404                 Boa Viagem                                         CE           356           978           TB1                 JO**********************                                                     2011-09-27 00:00:00         NULL
12399       C489895345345350000881240 2007-06-11 00:00:00     2306405                 Itapipoca                                          CE           876           093           TB1                 HA*************************                                                  2009-11-16 00:00:00         NULL
```

Resultado esperado:

```
ID          NUMERO                    DATAEMISSAOAPURADA      COD                     NOMEMUNICIPIORESIDENCIA                            UFRESIDENCIA CPF_1         CPF_2         FONTE               NOME                                                                         DATA                        DATA         
----------- ------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
12345       0000000000000009116092003 2007-11-19 00:00:00     4200051                 Abdon Batista                                      SC           123           321           TB1                 To***********                                                                2012-10-28 00:00:00         NULL
12347       C000000000000000000821022 2006-04-12 00:00:00     2302404                 Boa Viagem                                         CE           356           978           TB1                 JO**********************                                                     2011-09-27 00:00:00         NULL
12399       C489895345345350000881240 2007-06-11 00:00:00     2306405                 Itapipoca                                          CE           876           093           TB1                 HA*************************                                                  2009-11-16 00:00:00         NULL
```

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/512214-selecionando-item-max/?do=findComment&comment=2030107 veja se ajuda , subselect com MAX

Comment: Qual a versão do SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avalie

```
-- código #1
with MaisRecente as (
SELECT colunas,
       Seq= row_number() over (partition by CPF_1 order by DATAEMISSAOAPURADA desc)
  from tabela
)
SELECT colunas
  from MaisRecente
  where Seq = 1;
```

Comment: José vc é o mago do SQL segunda vez que vc me salva, Obrigadao cara!!

Answer (score 1):

O problema proposto pode ser resolvido da seguinte forma. Ainda é possível filtrar o select que obtem o *Max(DATAEMISSAOAPURADA)*

```
SELECT
ID          
,NUMERO 
,DATAEMISSAOAPURADA      
,COD                     
,NOMEMUNICIPIORESIDENCIA                            
,UFRESIDENCIA 
,CPF_1         
,CPF_2         
,FONTE               
,NOME
,DATA                        
FROM tabela A
where ID in (select ID from tabela B where DATAEMISSAOAPURADA = (SELECT MAX(DATAEMISSAOAPURADA) from tabela))
```

Comment: o problema é que isso só me retorna a maior data da tabela, eu gostaria de pegar a maior data para cada CPF existente pois a tabela possui múltiplos registros para o mesmo CPF

Comment: Neste caso pode adaptar o select feito neste link realizando as subqueries e ordenando pelo CPF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643187/query-help-matching-stage-and-returning-the-most-recent-one/45643653